# Python PYJQ map nested fields to multiple top level fields

Tags: python, json, mapping, jq

I'm trying to map some json data to a different schema. My original schema and the field in question look like this

```
"metrics":[  
  {  
     "type":"active_duration",
     "unit":"s",
     "value":135.0
  },
  {  
     "type":"basal_energy_burned",
     "unit":"kcal",
     "value":2371.7412956
  },
  {  
     "type":"distance",
     "unit":"m",
     "value":1510.36558533
  },
  {  
     "type":"active_energy_burned",
     "unit":"kcal",
     "value":295.203469907
  },
  {  
     "type":"steps",
     "unit":"count",
     "value":1877
  },
  {  
     "type":"energy_burned",
     "unit":"kcal",
     "value":2666.944765507
  }
   ],
```

and desired output

```
{
    "valueQuantity" : { "unit" : "count", "value" : 1877} ,
    "category" : "steps"
},
{
    "valueQuantity" : { "unit" : "kcal", "value" : 2666.944765507} ,
    "category" : "energy_burned"
}
....
```

I've tried this

```
import pyjq

t = pyjq.all("""
    {
        "valueQuantity" : .metrics[] | { "unit" : .unit, "value" : .value} ,
        "category" : .metrics[].type
    }""", data)
```

but the issue is that .metrics[] runs more than one and I end up having 36 rows (instead of 6)
Is there a way to achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean:

```
.metrics[] | { "valueQuantity" : { "unit" : .unit, "value" : .value}, "category" : .type }
```

which can be shortened to:

```
.metrics[] | { valueQuantity: {unit, value}, category: .type }
```